# File Upload - Allert if occurred error without submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I have multiple upload script and I will implement it to file with bigger html `form`which shoud be fill before submit. I need to allert error if selected file is more then written megabytes or type is wrong without submit.
P.S It would be nice if you tell me how to upload file with button and do not submit bigger form.
 Here is my code:

```js
var abc = 0; //Declaring and defining global increement variable

$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
                $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),        
                $("<br/><br/>")
                ));
    });

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file 
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                 abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1
    
    var z = abc - 1;
                var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");
               
       var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
               
       $(this).hide();
                $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'img', src: 'x.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                }));
            }
        });

//To preview image     
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    $('#upload').click(function(e) {
        var name = $(":file").val();
        if (!name)
        {
            alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);
form{
    background-color:white;
}
#maindiv{
    width:960px; 
    margin:10px auto; 
    padding:10px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
#formdiv{
    width:500px; 
    float:left; 
    text-align: center;
}
form{
    padding: 40px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
h2{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.upload{
    background-color:#ff0000;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px green;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
}
.upload:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#c20b0b;
    border:1px solid #c20b0b;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
}
#file{
    color:green;
    padding:5px; border:1px dashed #123456;
    background-color: #f9ffe5;
}
#upload{
    margin-left: 45px;
}

#noerror{
    color:green;
    text-align: left;
}
#error{
    color:red;
    text-align: left;
}


.abcd{
    text-align: center;
}

b{
    color:red;
}
#formget{
    float:right; 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">

            <div id="formdiv">
                <form action = "" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                    <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>
     <input type="text" required >
                    <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
                </form>
                <br/>
                <br/>
    <!-------Including PHP Script here------>
                <?php include "upload.php"; ?>
            </div>
           
     <!-- Right side div -->

        </div>
```

And my php file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pdf");  //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 4194304) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {//if file was not moved.
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery and html5

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Upload() {
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
        if (typeof (fileUpload.files) != "undefined") {
            var size = parseFloat(fileUpload.files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
            alert(size + " KB.");
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    }
</script>



<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is not working for me :( Tried upload more then 2mb and no allert if selecting file. Also `type=button` is unfunctional, just possible to click.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this u will get

```js
$("#aFile_upload").on("change", function (e) {

    var count=1;
    var files = e.currentTarget.files; // puts all files into an array

    // call them as such; files[0].size will get you the file size of the 0th file
    for (var x in files) {

        var filesize = ((files[x].size/1024)/1024).toFixed(4); // MB

        if (files[x].name != "item" && typeof files[x].name != "undefined" && filesize <= 10) { 

            if (count > 1) {

                approvedHTML += ", "+files[x].name;
            }
            else {

                approvedHTML += files[x].name;
            }

            count++;
        }
    }
});

$("#approvedFiles").val(approvedHTML);
```

Comment: by using jquery

Comment: Or i am editing it wrong or it is not working for me.  **aFile_upload** I changed for my ID. Then **toFixed(4)** I changed 4 ==> 2 and **filesize <= 2** to be sure that it is less then 2 mb.

Comment: Nothing happening and I can not even detect what is wrong.